# AMD second monitor detected but black

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, radeon

There are a lot of similar issues out there, but I haven't found any solution. I hope there is one.

I've attached my second monitor to my laptop. Ubuntu detects it just fine, it even extends the display (my mouse can leave my primary display and disappear), however the second screen just stays dark. It doesn't even register anything is attached to it.

The screen does work with a different laptop with Ubuntu.

This system is a Lenovo S440. There's 2 video adapters in it: Integrated Intel® HD Graphics 4400 and AMD Radeon™ HD 8670M Graphics 2GB. I don't know which one is connected to the HDMI port or how to find out.
I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I've tried installing amdgpu-pro drivers, but that just results in a login loop that seems to be only fixable by uninstalling said drivers. I've tried getting the binary drivers from AMD directly, however, it seems they only offer them for 14 and 15.

I don't need fancy 3d graphics and stuff. I just need my second monitor to work. Being relatively new to Ubuntu, I'm stuck and don't know the way forward.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a hardware problem.